# Storing and retrieving a structure on a queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

```
void addElement(struct BinaryTree *root, int data) {
    if (!root)
        return;
    BinaryTree *newNode = new BinaryTree;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    queue<BinaryTree> *myqueue = new queue<BinaryTree>;
    myqueue->push(*root); // Why do i have to dereference the object to store it in the queue;
    BinaryTree *temp;
    while (!myqueue->empty()) {
        temp = myqueue->front()
        //Throwing an error

        myqueue->pop();
        if (temp->left) {
            myqueue->push(*temp->left);

        } else {
            temp->left = newNode;
            break;
        }
        if (temp->right) {
            myqueue->push(*temp->right);
        } else {
            temp->right = newNode;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: C++ is not Java, you don't have to dynamically allocate all objects. Your queue object doesn't have to be a pointer and dynamically allocated, it can lead to pointer problems and memory leaks (which you have). Instead just define it as a normal non-pointer object `std::queue<BinaryTree> myqueue;`

Comment: As for the dereferencing, think a little about the type stored in the queue, compared to the type of `root`. Also, this mixup is the reason the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

> myqueue->push(*root); // Why do i have to dereference the object to store it in the queue;

This is because your queue template is instantiated with `BinaryTree` type which is not a pointer, so you cannot put inside of it variable of type `BinaryTree *root`. You have to dereference it using `*root`.

If you would have `queue<BinaryTree*>` then you could use `myqueue->push(root);`